# Javascript mouseover images

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, mouseover

im currently working on a section of a site in which there is a grid 9 images.  I'd like to have it so when your mouse moves over one of the images.  A div appears above the image containing some text.  any suggestions on how one would go about doing this? thanks!

heres what a part of the grid looks like

```
<div class = 'picture-container'>
            <div class = 'picture-wrapper' id = 'top-left'>
                <img src = 'ds-map.png' height = '100%' width = '100%'>
            </div>
            <div class = 'picture-wrapper' id = 'top-right'>
                <img src = 'ds-map.png' height = '100%' width = '100%'>
            </div>
            <div class = 'picture-wrapper' id = 'top-center'>
                <img src = 'ds-map.png' height = '100%' width = '100%'>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Care to show us what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either place a hidden div above each image and have it positioned via CSS...

```
<div class = 'picture-container'>
            <div class = 'picture-wrapper' id = 'top-left'>
                <div>with text</div><--- position this div relative to the container and hide/show it on rollover
                <img src = 'ds-map.png' height = '100%' width = '100%'>
            </div>
        </div>
```

OR
What I would do is make one hidden div after your body tag and then use javascript to show/position it and dynamically change the text

```
<div id="populateme"><div> <--- when mouse over the image modify this div to do what you want with javascript
<div class = 'picture-container'>
                <div class = 'picture-wrapper' id = 'top-left'>
                    <img src = 'ds-map.png' height = '100%' width = '100%'>
                </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want a [Tooltip](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tooltip), if you're already using jQuery the [jQuery UI Tooltip](http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/) might be a good option, they can be attached to any element.